# Odoo 13 - Computed Fields - not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

I have a Model `ks.register` has a field `meter_ids` which is a computed field added in XML notebook tag as a Page.

Computed field be like:

```
meter_ids = fields.One2many('ks.meter', string='Meters', compute="_get_register")
```

Below is the computed method for that field

```
def _get_register(self):
    ids = {}
    if not self.ids:
        return meter_ids
 query = 
    cr.execute(query)
    meter_records = cr.fetchall()
    for i in meter_records:
        ids[i[0]] = i[1] if i[1] != [None] else []
    return ids
```

when I go to the `ks.register` XML page and hit the tree view. I see

`Something Went Wrong ks.register(569909,).ids` Pop up error.

Can someone tell me what went wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to help.

You're first searching records in **`ks.meter`** model which are link with **`ks.register`** model? For this you've created **`One2many`** field.

So instead of writing query you can also do this. You can use **`Many2one`** field for searching in **`ks.meter`**

```
for i in self:
    records = self.env['ks.meter'].search([('Many2one_field', '=', i.id)])
    getting_ids = [j.id for j in records]
    i.meter_ids = [6, 0, getting_ids]
```